# ITSUMIF Criteria for Cells That Don't Match a Condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet that looks like the following:

```
# |A           |B
-----------------------------
1 |Expenses    |Category
2 |$5          |Food
3 |$10         |Entertainment
4 |$10         |Haircut
```

What I want is to create a section that lists the sum for each category. Something that is organized like this:

```
# |H            |I
-----------------------------
1 |Category     |Total Expenses
2 |Food         |
3 |Entertainment|
4 |Other        |
```

Summing up the categories for Food and Enterainment were pretty easy. I used the SUMIF function to check the range of the B "Category" column against a cell in the H "Category" column, which added up the values if they matched. For instance, "I2" had a formula just like this:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B$999, H2, A$2:A$99)
```

However, I'm having a really hard time setting up the "Other" category. What I want is for it to display any values that have a category that does not show up in H column (for instance, "Haircut"). I tried doing the following:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B$999, NOT(OR(H2,H3)), A$2:A$99)
```

But that doesn't seem to capture any cells. Ultimately, I want for the criteria section of SUMIF to capture cells that do not contain the values found in a range of other cells.

EDIT: This is for a spreadsheet that is for a client that is not very computer saavy, so any solution should ideally be one that puts very little burden on an end user (e.g. doesn't require them to understand that macros are okay). Also the full spreadsheet includes a date column, so sorting by category won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUMIFS` allows you to specify more than one condition (in Excel 2007 or later) so you could use this formula

`=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"<>"&H2,B:B,"<>"&H3)`

That will sum column A where the corresponding column B value is not equal to H2 **AND** not equal to H3

If you have a longer list of items to exclude then that way will make for a long formula so another way to exclude a range would be using `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNA(MATCH(B2:B100,H2:H5,0))+0,A2:A100)`

That will sum A2:A100 when the corresponding column B value doesn't match any of the values in H2:H5

Comment: I've changed this to the accepted answer because it directly answers the specific question I had about SUMIF, although there might be better alternatives to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `Pivot Table`.

Select one of the cells of your table, let's say `A1`. Create a Pivot Table by clicking: Insert > Pivot Table. Click ok.

At this point you will have a `Pivot Table` created in a new sheet. To calculate what you want drag and drop the `Category` from the filed list, in the box at the right side of the table, to the `Row Labels`, then, drag and drop `Expenses` to the `∑ Values`.

**EDIT**

As you asked in your question, the `Pivot Table` doesn't need to be created in a separate sheet. Instead of clicking OK when the Pivot Table prompts a dialog, you can specify where you want to create your Pivot Table.

Also, remember to refresh the table whenever it's contents are modified, by right-clicking the Pivot Table and then clicking Refresh.

**EDIT 2**

I'm sorry, I complete misread your question, you were able to calculate the sum of the Categories, so you don't need a Pivot Table.. What you need is to sum the others categories, my suggest:

Instead of try to sum all the categories that weren't summed, why don't you sum the total from A1:A999 and subtract all the summed values in the I column?

Let's suppose your `Other` field is at H4:

> =SUM(A$1:A$999) - SUM(I$2:I$3)

Comment: Is there any way to make it auto-refresh? I'm creating this for others who have never used pivot tables and I'm not sure that they will remember to hit Refresh every time they update.

Comment: Instructions [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/06/13/auto-refresh-a-pivot-table-in-excel/) tell me that I can make it work with a macro, but if clients not remembering to refresh is bad enough, I think they'll get freaked out by a macro security warning. I'm afraid I can't accept this solution if this is the case.

Comment: Well, it is a Macro I was looking for, actually. So, Macro isn't a good solution either? What about `refresh when open the file`?

Comment: A macro would be fine if I were using it, but it's for a client. I did see "refresh when open the file", which I've already checked, but I'd ideally like something that updates instantly with the value totals. I guess I can't have it all and I'll have to compromise on something?

Comment: What about my `Edit 2`?

Comment: Thanks for it. The pivot table actually is an excellent replacement for columns H and I as a whole, especially since, after it is refreshed, it lists all of the categories, thus eliminating the need for an Other category. If only it could refresh automatically without macros, I would totally accept that answer. Edit 2 looks good, but I think that Scott's answer is a bit more future-proof, so I'm going to accept that one.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way to do this is to sort the data by category and use SUBTOTAL.  You can either use the function SUBTOTAL repeatedly or (the easier way) highlight your sorted A and B columns and use Subtotal from Outline in the Data Ribbon (I forget which menu it's under in earlier versions of Excel).  That will automatically insert subtotals whenever the category changes, include a grand total, and set up outline processing so you can collapse or expand the subtotals.

Subtotal is *very* handy for this kind of thing.  It supports multiple layers of totals, so you could have separate subtotals by department, by category in department, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, sorting the data by category isn't an option, otherwise I would probably just be able to use SUM. The full table includes a column for dates.

Comment: Sort by category, use automatic subtotal. Paste the subtotal lines as values, then resort back by date. If that works for you, save it in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting `I4` to `=SUM(A$2:A$99) - SUM(I$2:I3)` –– all the data in Column `B` minus the (sub) totals you’ve already accumulated in Column `I`.  If you need to be able to add (and/or delete) categories with a minimum of fuss and bother, look at

```
=SUM(A$2:A$99) - SUM(OFFSET(I$2,0,0,ROW()-2,1))
```

where the `ROW()` function figures out what row it is in (i.e., what row is the “Other” row). 
Subtract 2 for Row `1` and the current row; for example, if you have eight summed categories, in Cells `H2:H9`, then `Other` is in `H10`, and you want to sum `I2:I9`, which is eight (10-2) rows.

Comment: Thanks for realizing that there was a simpler solution than what I was asking for :-)